# WebBLE support in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I am trying to interact with a BLE device through webBle. I was able to do this in Chrome in Android. I was trying to do that same thing in iOS Chrome as well using.

```
navigator.bluetooth
```

But it was not working and after some research, I found that it's supported only in macOS and not in iOS.

I was wondering if there is any way for me to interact with the BLE device on iOS using a browser?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Bluetooth is not supported by Mobile Safari or WkWebView and has not been added by major 3rd-party browsers on iOS. There is however a Web Bluetooth-specific browser called [WebBLE](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/webble/id1193531073) which includes an implementation of Web Bluetooth. It is open source software with code available [on GitHub](https://github.com/daphtdazz/WebBLE).